# Remove opencart product model

Tags: php, opencart

How can I remove the "model required" from the model field in the admin product page in opencart (3.0.3.2), and make it an optional field like the rest of the fields in the data tab? model required screenshot.

I am tried to hide this piece of Code but [(click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5TyQ.png) isn't working

> admin\controller\catalog\product.php

```
/*if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) > 64)) {
                $this->error['model'] = $this->language->get('error_model');
            } */
```

Comment: You can remove required from product_form.twig files.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove red asterisk
In file:admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig
Find:

```
<div class="form-group required">
```

before:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-model">{{ entry_model }}</label>
```

replace with:

```
<div class="form-group">
```

Also comment this:

```
<!--
{% if error_model %}
   <div class="text-danger">{{ error_model }}</div>
{% endif %}
-->
```

And of course in corresponding controller file this should be commented like you already done...

```
/*if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['model']) > 64)) { $this->error['model'] = $this->language->get('error_model'); } */
```

The best way to do that modifications to use OCMOD.

Comment: I tried your solution but still not working. Anyway thank you.

Comment: After you made all changes you must refresh modifications in admin dashboard and clear cache also in main admin dashboard blue gear icon in the right upper corner.

Comment: red asterisk did not disappear? Or you got some errors? Please check error log.

Comment: Unfortunately the red star did not disappear. Error log shows: PHP Warning:  
DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 10 PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/opencart/system/storage/vendor/scss.inc.php on line 1753